# Retrieving Kafka broker properties from a client

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve all the configuration properties of a kafka broker using a shell command?

For eg, something like:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper ${broker_ip}:2181 --entity-type brokers --describe
```

The above doesn't return any value, but I hope the question is clearer looking at the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the configuration in the log file of Kafka broker which is printed on broker start up.  I am afraid that there is such command that lists all the configuration parameters of a Kafka broker.

Some more information regarding Kafka brokers can be retrieved through Zookeeper (however these commands won't give you the kafka configuration). To do so,

Enter Zookeeper shell:

```
zookeeper-shell localhost:2181
```

and run

```
get /brokers/ids/0
```

to retrieve some further information for broker with id `0`.

**EDIT:**

Although `kafka-configs` claims to be able to describe kafka configuration, command

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0
Configs for broker 0 are:
```

doesn't seem to return any configuration parameters.

Comment: You can get broker configs via JMX as well, I believe

Comment: @cricket_007 Correct.

Comment: zookeeper endpoint must be used for "kafka-configs" option. Example : bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zoo1:2181/kafka --describe --entity-type brokers --entity-name <broker-id>

Comment: kafka-config only appears to return configs that were set via kafka-config.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Kafka 2.13-2.7.0` and kafka-configs is working for me:

```
kafka-configs.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9091 --entity-type brokers --describe --all
```

The above will give you the properties of all the associated brokers as well.