# Any way to confirm Kafka consumer properties?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to confirm that Kafka Consumer config is working correctly.  I am setting some consumer property values to non-default values (e.g. session.timeout.ms, heartbeat.interval.ms).  Is there a way to query them and ensure that they have been set to the specific values I define in my properties?

I've searched online, but I can't seem to find any guidance on how to query group controller for these configurations.

The closest approach I found is using kafka-consumer-groups.sh, but that does not provide all the details.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Some further clarification based on feedback:
I do use logging, however I don't think that's what I want to check.

Let me try and clarify a bit further.  Let's take session.timeout.ms as an example.  That setting is used by the group coordinator to determine if a particular consumer is alive.  So I would think the group coordinator (which is a kafka broker) must be aware of this setting server-side.  So if I set session timeout to a non-default value, I am wondering if there is a way to query the broker to get this setting.  If I use logging, I will get the configuration setting on the object that's created when I created the Kafka consumer.  It is not providing me with values from the broker.  I hope this clarifies the ask.  Please correct me if my understand is wrong.

Comment: VerifiableProducer.sh and VerfiableConsumer.sh might come handy here. https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Comment: you should see them in loga at kafka consumer or producer start up

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which client are you using, java/scala or something else? Default java kafka-clients lib uses embedded slf4j logging for kafka producer/consumer properties. In this case check that you have enabled INFO logging for package `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer` or its parent.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify a bit more.  I don't think logging is the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup logging via log4j or Slf4j, the `ConsumerConfig` object gets printed out in the application logs and will show all loaded properties

Otherwise, they *might* be shown in JMX as well, but I'm not too sure

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I do use logging, but I don't think that's what I am after.  I've updated my question to clarify a bit further.

Comment: The consumer doesn't know about broker configs. I think think you're asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873361/retrieving-kafka-broker-properties-from-a-client